# proxychains - cannot get wget working

Tags: linux

I have configured ProxyChains to use `127.0.0.1:1080` as the only socks server. All the DNS requests are proxied through the above server.

I am able to use Firefox with ProxyChains properly, but there is some issue with wget. Whenever I use `proxychains wget` it first tries to connect to my university's proxy server and then it tries to connect to my local proxy server.

The output of the command `proxychains wget www.google.com` is as follows:

```
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
--2010-11-26 22:14:38--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving **********... |DNS-request| **********
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response|: ********** is not exist
failed: Unknown error.
wget: unable to resolve host address `**********'
```

********** above represents my university's proxy server host name.

Answer (score 4):

in file `/usr/lib/proxychains3/proxyresolv`

change 4.2.2.2 to 8.8.8.8

or use env `PROXYRESOLV_DNS`

---

also you can make proxychains doesn't proxy DNS request,

in `proxychains.conf` comment the `proxy_dns` setting

Answer (score 3):

My Problem was resolved after becoming root ("sudo sh") and executing the same command.

Running the command as `proxychains sudo wget google.com` worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try defining your proxy's address with a shell environment variable. There's a brief section in the [wget manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Proxies.html) on configuring for proxies.

Comment: I want to use proxychains to run wget. I dont want to define proxies in wget.